# EF6 Code First: Using Fluent API to declare a Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working on an insurance industry related app with EF 6 and Code First.  For this app, each Account can have multiple Policies and each Policy can have multiple Transactions. Further, each Account must have a relationship to an Identity (Name, Address, City, etc.).  The Policy also has a relationship to an Identity, but it is optional.

Because of Account -> Identity and Account ->> Policy -> Identity, I have found that I need to use Fluent API to set the WillCascadeDelete to False for at least one of those paths.

My question is how do I configure the Account.IdentityId and Policy.InsuredIdentityId properties to be foreign keys?  I've avoided adding any navigation/foreign key fields to the identity class because there should never be a reason to navigate from an identity to another class.  Is that why I'm having a tough time figuring this out?

```
public class Account
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long IdentityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Identity Identity { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Policy> Policies { get; set; }
}

public class Policy
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public bool UseAccountIdentity { get; set; }
    public long InsuredIdentityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Identity InsuredIdentity { get; set; }
}

 public class Identity 
{        
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}

public class AccountConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
    public AccountConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(a => a.Identity).WithOptional(x => x.Account).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasMany(a => a.Policies).WithRequired(p => p.Account).HasForeignKey(p => p.AccountId);
    }
}

public class PolicyConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Policy>
{
    public PolicyConfiguration()
    {
        HasOptional(p => p.InsuredIdentity).WithOptionalPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

As a side question, are there any good books or other reference sources for EF Code First?  I have Julia Lerman's Programming Entity Framework: Code First, which is fine for the examples that it does cover but it doesn't cover enough cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, `public ICollection<Policy> Policies { get; set; }` should be `public virtual ICollection<Policy> Policies { get; set; }`.

You can only map EF foreign key properties when one side of the relationship is a one, and the other is a many. Any time you have a 1:1 or 1:0..1 relationship, the dependent entity will take the same primary key as the principal. In these cases there cannot be a foreign key because the dependent's foreign key IS its primary key.

So for this:

```
HasRequired(a => a.Identity).WithOptional(x => x.Account)
```

... account's Id will be the same value as the identity's Id. Meaning, you can completely remove the `IdentityId` property from the `Account` entity. However I don't understand how that code compiles, because `Identity` does not have an `Account` navigation property..?

When it comes to your Policy mapping, is this really how you want to do it? You say that a Policy can have an optional relationship to an Identity, but the way you are doing it:

```
HasOptional(p => p.InsuredIdentity).WithOptionalPrincipal()
```

...means that an `Identity` can only be related (directly) do one `Policy`. What's wrong with making the mapping look like this?

```
HasOptional(p => p.InsuredIdentity).WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.InsuredIdentityId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

With the above, you still do not have any navigation properties from `Identity` to `Policy`. You don't need one, you can just invoke `.WithMany()` as a no-arg. However this tells the database to set up `Identity` as the principal, and `Policy` as the dependent, so you have a normal fk relationship in the db, and you still cannot navigate to a `Policy` from an `Identity` in code.

Other comments:

> The Policy also has a relationship to an Identity, but it is optional.

This means that `Policy.InsuredIdentityId` should be a `System.Nullable<long>`.

Comment: Not quite what I'm trying to accomplish, but I think this has me on the right path.

Comment: I'm sure this is a complex domain, and there are probably a few different ways to model it. Note you can always make things zero-or-one-to-many in the EF model to enable fk properties, and just omit navigation properties on either side for unidirectional relationships. Any time you have a true 1:1 or 1:0..1 though, you really do want them to share the same primary key, in which case foreign keys don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was conceptual. While typically an Identity would only apply to one Account (leading me to visualize it as a 1:1), theoretically the Identity could be used more then once and therefore on more then one Account. If I use the following configuration, I get what I was looking for. Its then up to me to enforce any rules such as an Identity can only be used with one Account (but as many Policies as are needed)

```
public class IdentityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Identity>
{
    public IdentityConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(i => i.Accounts).WithRequired(i => i.Identity).HasForeignKey(a => a.IdentityId);            
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I could have made the Identity the Primary entity and the Account the optional dependent.  this would work because all Accounts have an Identity but not all Identities are linked to an Account. Account would no longer have its own key.

That's not intuitive, which is somewhat concerning.

Comment: Nothing about insurance is intuitive.

Comment: Can't argue with that. Its taking me a few minutes to wrap my mind about it, but leaning toward Identity as the primary entity 1:1 with Account. Thanks.

Comment: Remember as a 1:1, you will have to create and delete both in the same transaction. You can't create one, save it, then link up the other.

Comment: Isn't that only the case if its required on both ends?  In my case, Account can't be created without an Identity, but an Identity can be created without an Account, ie to be used for a Policy.

Comment: Ok, then we're just talking about semantics here. I would call that a 1:0..1 (one to zero or one). You are right, you can make it optional on one end and delay creation of the required side.

Comment: Thanks again.  And you're right, its a 1:0..1.  I'm still getting used  to it being primary, lol.